# Script using Python API and Windows task scheduler

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, windows, arcgis-python-api

I have a Python script that uses the Python API to logging into the server, stop geocode services, rebuild locators and start services. I'm using task scheduler on a server machine where other Python scripts work correctly in task scheduler.

Is there a way to use Windows task scheduler to run this script? I've tried this [Schedule a Python Script using Windows Task Scheduler](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-documents/schedule-a-python-script-using-windows-task-scheduler/ta-p/915861) and [Run stand-alone scripts](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/get-started/using-conda-with-arcgis-pro.htm) without success.

Windows server 2019, Here's a screenshot of the settings in task scheduler [image]

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? And can you post what your settings are currently in the Task Scheduler? From my experience, it is very sensitive.

Comment: The details surrounding "without success" would be very useful in identifying a solution.

Comment: By "without success" I mean that task scheduler does not trigger the script to run at the scheduled time. The script works fine in the IDE but doesn't work when a task is created in task scheduler. The settings in task scheduler are the same as other tasks that have successfully run other python scripts.

Comment: I see you have "D:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\Scripts\propy.bat" as your Program/script parameter on the Actions tab. Maybe you have your reasons, I'm not sure. I have that set to either "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\pythonw.exe" or "...\python.exe".

Comment: I've tried setting the Program/script parameter on the Actions tab to: "D:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\pythonw.exe" this at least starts the script in task scheduler because it can write the script progress to a log with a different error now. Thanks!!!